# Python - 5 random items from user chosen lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, printing, dictionary, user-input

I am trying to print one number from 5 different user chosen lists.
This is the code

```
import random

d = {'january':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'febuary':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'march':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'april':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'may':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'june':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'july':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
,'august':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']}

items = raw_input("Pick 5 and separate them by a comma:" + ','.join(d)
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 = items.split(',')

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[item1])

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[item2])

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[item3])

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[item4])

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[item5])

raw_input ()
```

I keep getting a

```
SyntaxError on line 13;
    item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 = items.split(',')
```

I have also tried

```
items = raw_input("Pick 5 separated by comma:" + ','.join(d)
splitItems = items.split(',')

#print roles

print 'picked:', random.choice(d[splitItems[0]])
print 'picked:', random.choice(d[splitItems[1]])
print 'picked:', random.choice(d[splitItems[2]])
print 'picked:', random.choice(d[splitItems[3]])
print 'picked:', random.choice(d[splitItems[4]])
```

which also had a

```
SyntaxError on line 13;
    splitItems = items.split(',')
```

Edit: fixing mistakes

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the `raw_input` line.  This is a common problem -- When you get a SyntaxError that doesn't make sense, always look to the line above -- It's likely you didn't close a parenthesis or `{` or `[`

Comment: Seems like my answer was based on `typo` only.

Comment: !! Perfect, thank you so much for this answer and the ones from earlier today! Finally worked it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close paren at the end of

```
items = raw_input("Pick 5 and separate them by a comma:" + ','.join(d)
```